# K-modes clusters evolvings

Tags: cluster-analysis

After performing a clustering of a dataset using k-modes, I have to evolve the clusters in time so, is there a way to automatically adjust the centroids as long as the data points changes its property values?.

I mean. I am clustering a big set of data with categorical values. However, these data points change in time (its categorical values) so I want to know if there is any way to make adjustments on the K centroids (or even in the K number) as long as the data points are slightly changing over time. I can recalculate the distance from each data point with the centroids and move the data point to another cluster but this would consider the centroids as fixed and I guess they could also change as data points change.

Re-Clustering is a very heavy task in time so there is a need to make this adjustments in a more efficient way. I am searching on the literature but I havent found any information about it.

Anybody knows if this is possible or any study related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reclustering, use the previously found centers.

They shouldn't change much, and converge quickly.

Comment: I do not know if I follow you. In which way I can use the original cluster centroids?. I do not know how I can converge them without reclustering starting from the new space of data points. Do you mean I recluster but setting the cluster centroids to the original ones as starting point?.

Comment: Yes. That should take much fewer iterations.

Comment: But this would only solve the issue regarding the convergence of the cluster centroids to the new scenario but it wouldn't consider the case where new cluster arise (I mean, the K value changes).